# How to tell live555 rtspclient to send setupCommand with specific connection?

Tags: c++, live555

I am connection to the camera using live555 testRTSPClient application (http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/#testProgs)
`./testRTSPClient rtsp://....`

but it does not get any video stream. The problem seems to be that the camera tells in its SDP that it has two connections

```
...
s=/videoinput_1:0/h264_1/media.stm
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
m=video 11800 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 239.0.3.180/1
...
```

and testRTSPClient selects the last multicast one. In the Setup command the testRTSPClient tells following

```
...
User-Agent: ./testRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2017.06.04)
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;port=11800-11801
...
```

When connecting to another camera, which SDP contains only one connection (`c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0`) then everything is fine.

1) So the first question is that is it possible to force the testRTSPClient to select the **UDP** unicast instead? The ffplay streams from the camera nicely and Wireshark show that ffplay setups the transports with UDP unicast and not multicast.

2) Secondly, I am using my own C++ example similar to testRTSPClient. In the subSession setup I use the `RTSPClient::sendSetupCommand` function

```
rtspClient->sendSetupCommand(*subsession, continueAfterSetup, False, False, False);
```

but my program still does the Setup with multicast like the testRTSPClient. The parameter `forceMulticastOnUnspecified` does not seem to make any difference here. Currently, I see that the only option is to remove the second multicast connection substring from the SDP.

```
void continueAfterDescribe(RTSPClient* rtspClient, int resultCode, char* resultString)
{
   ...

    char* const sdpDescription = resultString;
    env << "Got a SDP description:\n" << sdpDescription << "\n";

    // Hypothetical new code
    if (user determined transport == UDP unicast)
      removeSecondConnection(sdpDescription);  

    // Create a media session object from this SDP description:
    MediaSession::createNew(env, sdpDescription);
    ...
```

But it is a hack in my mind. Is there any other option to select the unicast using live555 C++ API? I know that there is a TCP unicast option, but I am not interested in it for now.